# how can I call re-registration and send registration to server manually on pjsua2?

Tags: android, asterisk, pjsip, pjsua2

I'm using pjsip in my android chat application(using pjsua2).
All things is good and I can register and make call with others successfully.
default re-registration of pjsua2 is 300s and after this time a re-register request will send to server.
And I know how to change this time , but some times I need to call re-registration manually depends on some events.
how can I call re-registration and send registration to server manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone need to call re-registration with pjsua2, call bellow function from Account class :

```
public void setRegistration(boolean renew) throws java.lang.Exception {
    pjsua2JNI.Account_setRegistration(swigCPtr, this, renew);
}
```

Comment: can you please let me know how can i change default reregistration delay 300 second after sip failure registration at   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64241763/how-to-change-default-time-delay-300-second-pjsua-2-android-retry-registratio

Comment: And how can i pause and unpause  video streaming during  a video call , provided voice call stays . (just like feature on whats app - u can hide and unhide video during a call) ...at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63702759/how-to-pause-and-unpause-video-transmission-using-android-pjsua-2/64259445#64259445

Comment: Hasein Kord can you please guide me I am getting this error?
account.cpp !pjsua_acc_set_registration(id, renew) error: Invalid value or argument (PJ_EINVAL) (status=70004) [../src/pjsua2/account.cpp:1029]

Comment: @DharmeshPatel , It's better not call setRegistration as I said , You should change this configs (setFirstRetryIntervalSec - 
setRetryIntervalSec - 
setRandomRetryIntervalSec -) - And if you need register again its better to remove last account and add account again.