# How to change default time delay 300 second ( Pjsua 2 Android) retry registration after registration failure?

Tags: android, pjsip, pjsua2

How can i change the default pjsua2 reregistration after registration failure. Currently it has been set to 300 second. I wish to set to retry registration after a registration failure to around 60 second.

i went through documentation ...but some how i am not able to implement them on sample android pjsua2 app.

> unsigned timeoutSec Optional interval for registration, in seconds.
>
> If the value is zero, default interval will be used
> (PJSUA_REG_INTERVAL, 300 seconds).
>
> unsigned retryIntervalSec Specify interval of auto registration retry
> upon registration failure (including caused by transport problem), in
> second.
>
> Set to 0 to disable auto re-registration. Note that if the
> registration retry occurs because of transport failure, the first
> retry will be done after firstRetryIntervalSec seconds instead. Also
> note that the interval will be randomized slightly by some seconds
> (specified in reg_retry_random_interval) to avoid all clients
> re-registering at the same time.
>
> See also firstRetryIntervalSec and randomRetryIntervalSec settings.
>
> Default: PJSUA_REG_RETRY_INTERVAL

link : https://www.pjsip.org/docs/book-latest/html/reference.html

Answer (score 0):

Why you're unable to implement this? What's wrong when you are trying to?

Actually, you answerd youreself already. You should find initialization of `AccountRegConfig` object and set value of `retryIntervalSec` property.

```
AccountRegConfig regCfg = accCfg.getRegConfig();
regCfg.setRegistrarUri("sip:pjsip.org");
regCfg.setRetryIntervalSec(60);
account = app.addAcc(accCfg);
```

If this is not working, what misbehave you are seeing?

Comment: Can you please have a look at my question .. i wasnt able to improve video quality from android pjsip pjsua2 sample app, which has a very bad video qualtiy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65410821/how-can-i-improve-video-quality-of-pjsip-pjsua2-sample-android-app

Answer (score 0):

You can use bellow code, and read comments and set values depends on your needs.

```
             accCfg = new AccountConfig();

             /*
             * Specify interval of auto registration retry upon registration failure 
              (including
             * caused by transport problem), in second. Set to 0 to disable auto re- 
             registration.
             * Note that if the registration retry occurs because of transport 
             failure, the first
             * retry will be done after reg_first_retry_interval seconds instead. Also 
             note that
             * the interval will be randomized slightly by some seconds (specified in 
             reg_retry_
             * random_interval) to avoid all clients re-registering at the same time.
             * */
             accCfg.getRegConfig().setFirstRetryIntervalSec(3);
             accCfg.getRegConfig().setRetryIntervalSec(10);

            /*
             * This specifies maximum randomized value to be added/subtracted to/from 
             the
             * registration retry interval specified in reg_retry_interval and
             * reg_first_retry_interval, in second. This is useful to avoid all 
             clients
             * re-registering at the same time. For example, if the registration retry 
             interval
             * is set to 100 seconds and this is set to 10 seconds, the actual 
             registration retry
             * interval will be in the range of 90 to 110 seconds.
             */
            accCfg.getRegConfig().setRandomRetryIntervalSec(7);
            /*
             * Optional interval for registration, in seconds. If the value is zero, 
            default
             * interval will be used (PJSUA_REG_INTERVAL, 300 seconds).
             */
            accCfg.getRegConfig().setTimeoutSec(65);

            /*
             * Specify the number of seconds to refresh the client registration before 
             the
             * registration expires.
             * Default: PJSIP_REGISTER_CLIENT_DELAY_BEFORE_REFRESH, 5 seconds
             */
            accCfg.getRegConfig().setDelayBeforeRefreshSec(10);
```

Comment: I have tried this but cant change the EXPIRES interval ... It remains at 300..